# How to get all rows from related table including columns from pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables (students, tests) and a pivot table (student_test).
From a specific student, I want to get all rows from the tests including the related columns from student_test. If there are no test results the values of the columns of student_test are NULL.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
public function all_tests()
{
    $collection = new Collection();

    foreach (Tests::all() as $test) {
        if (($model = $this->tests->find($test->id)) === null) {
            $model = $test;
        }

        $collection->push($model);
    }

    return $collection;
}
```

I have the following models.

app/Http/Models/Student.php:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    // Attributes: id, first_name, last_name

    public function tests()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Test::class);
    }
}
```

app/Http/Models/Test.php:

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tests';

    // Attributes: id, name

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

I want to return a collection of Test models with the extra column (test_result) from student_test table.

Comment: It seems you have 3 models over here Students, Tests, and Results ?

Comment: I have 2 models (Students, Tests) and 1 pivot table (student_test). Sorry, the pivot table is without '_restults'.

Comment: Laravel is only using the table `student_test` to get the model either from `tests` table or `students` table its not taking any extra columns into account

Comment: I think you need an extra model called `Result` that has a many to one relation with a test and a one to one relation with a student

Comment: That's a nice way of looking at it.

Comment: I added an answer for you that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

Laravel is only using the table `student_test` to get the model either from tests table or students table its not taking any extra columns into account.

I think you need an extra model called `Result` that has a many to one relation with a test and a one to many relation with a student

Add the model with the result columns

> Add this to the `Student` model

```
public function results()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
}
```

> Add this to the `Test` model

```
public function results()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
}
```

> Add this to the `Result` model

```
public function test()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Test::class);
}

public function student()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```

And add the correct columns.

This way you can do:

```
$student->results->whereHas('test', function ($query) use ($test) {
    $query->where('id', '=', $test->id);
})->get();
```

Or:

```
$test->results->whereHas('student', function ($query) use ($student) {
        $query->where('id', '=', $student->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: So it is never a good idea to have pivot table with extra values? Should you always use a model 'in between'?

Comment: I think that the implementation of the `results()`-method at the *Student* model needs to be: `return $this->hasMany(Result::class);`.

Comment: That is what I put right? I changed it from my comment earlier.

Comment: No, there is something else:


_Add this to the Student model_

`public function results()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}`

Comment: ahh i see sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187251/discussion-between-josjojo-and-mike).

Answer (score 0):

i think this code can be help you.
you must use 'with' by relation model

```
$collection = new Collection();

foreach (Tests::all()->with('tests') as $test) {
    if (($model = $this->tests->find($test->id)) === null) {
        $model = $test;
    }

    $collection->push($model);
}

return $collection;
```

Comment: `Tests::all()` returns a Collection. Collections doesn't have a `with()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mike's solution, I came up with the following:

```
$student_id = 1;

$test_results = Test::crossJoin('students')
    ->leftJoin('results', [
        ['students.id', '=', 'results.student_id'],
        ['test.id', '=', 'results.test_id'],
    ])
    ->where('students.id', $student_id)
    ->get();
```